# Weird characters jump out of arrays when used with get file contents

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

Hi this is a portion of my code which when ever output, the array $data2[0] seems to always output weird characters. It doesn't happens in $data2[1] or $data[2]..??? I been trying to figure this out for 2 days.

```
<?php
$filename = "../file/attendance_log/1414001189.txt";

$contents = file_get_contents($filename);

$contents = str_replace("\"","",$contents);

$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
$numrows = count($lines);


$x = 0;


for ($numrows; $x < $numrows; $x++)
{

echo $data2[0]; 

$data2 = explode(",", $lines[$x]);

echo $time = mktime(0,0,1,$data2[1],$data2[0],$data2[2]);

$user_no = $data2[3];

$item_no = $data2[4];

$quantity = $data2[5];

$waste = $data2[6];

$job_no = $data2[7];

}

?>
```

Comment: this is usually the output Day㈀㈀21㔀22㈀㈀, the file content is Day,Month,Year,Employee No.,Job Type.,Quantity,Waste,Order No. 
22,10,2014,15,18,50,3,1
21,10,2014,16,16,100,1,2
5,10,2014,18,13,54,2,3
22,10,2014,19,10,33,1,4
22,10,2014,25,22,24,5,5

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to explode and use the first line which has the column names in it

i slightly rewrote what you had to accomodate that and also not use a counter and

setting the default timezone too so you get what i think you were looking for

```
<?php
$filename = "../file/attendance_log/1414001189.txt";

$contents = file_get_contents($filename);

$contents = str_replace("\"","",$contents);

$lines = explode("\n", $contents);

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

if (count($lines)){

    $lines = array_slice($lines, 1);

    foreach ($lines as $line){

        $data2 = explode(",", $line);

        if (count($data2) == 8){

            echo $data2[0];

            $time = mktime(0,0,1,$data2[1],$data2[0],$data2[2]);

            echo $time . '<br>';

            $user_no = $data2[3];

            $item_no = $data2[4];

            $quantity = $data2[5];

            $waste = $data2[6];

            $job_no = $data2[7];

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted. For some reasons wondering why it wasn't working. I tried removing the first line of column names but the first line first array still generate errors. Anyway thanks now its working.

Answer (score 0):

I had found the answer. It is because when the user save the file. It saved as Unicode UTF. It should save as Unicode UTF-8, that way there won't be any problems.